# How to change '55' that is read from a file, to an integer

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to read a number from a text file and increment it by 8 IF that number + 8 isnt over 100:

```
num='head -c 4 storage.txt' // num = '55'
```

how do i do an equivelant atoi, reading a char from file, converting to int.
then perform the below:

```
if(num+8 >= 100)
   return
else num+=8
```

then read back into the file

```
num>storage.txt
```

Comment: You are reading 4 characters/bytes. Is this a packed, 4-byte integer, or just a numeric literal with 4 digits (so a number between 0 and 9999, say)?

Comment: In other words, show us an example of what `storage.txt` looks like.

Comment: the text file would be any number between 5 and 90 as the assignment required from school, i guess i only need to read 2 bytes not 4.

so i'm only reading 1 number from this file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most (if not all) Unis shells, all variables store strings. The concept of converting to integer doesn't exist.

But, some operations are able to take strings as input, internally convert them to integers, perform the operation then return the result as a string.

In bash, what you intent to do can be written as:

```
if [ $(($num + 8)) -lt 100 ]
then
  num=$((num+8))
fi
```

Comment: thank you so much!

 but now I have a syntax error and it says: unexpected end of file

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  This is one approach that uses arithmetic expansion (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html).

```
if [ $(( num + 8 )) -lt 100 ]; then
    num=$(( num + 8 ))
fi

echo $num > storage.txt
```